# Add the path _vti_bin/Lists.asmx to an ASP.NET MVC 2 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asmx, routes

I am trying to add the path **/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx** to my **ASP.NET MVC 2** web application.

I am registering the route as follows:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Add(new Route("_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", new ListsHandler()));
```

where ListHandler is defined as:

```
public sealed class ListsHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    #region IRouteHandler Members

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But when I start the MVC application and try to navigate to http://localhost:8888/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, I get an HTTP 404 error, rather than an exception raised.

Is this even possible in MVC? Do I need to add an Lists.asmx ASPX web service file to my project in a particular place (I cannot create the _vti_bin folder in the Visual Studio project)?

**Update:** Darin's response enabled http://localhost:8888/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx to work now (the only difference is the order of the route definitions). But now, requesting the 'About' page of the default MVC 2 project site results in a request to  http://localhost:8888/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?action=About&controller=Home, not to the home controller!

Apparently the order in which the routes are defined matters.

Comment: Is `_vti_bin` folder a SharePoint convention? I recall seeing folders with that naming convention hosting SharePoint web services? (I could be totally wrong)

Comment: Yes, it is used by SharePoint, and I am actually attempting to mimic the SharePoint service interface in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Here are the steps I did:

1. Start VS2010
2. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project using the template
3. Modify Global.asax to look like this:

   ```
   public sealed class ListsHandler : IRouteHandler
   {
       public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

           routes.Add(new Route("_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", new ListsHandler()));

           routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
       }

       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Start the application and navigate to http://localhost:1505/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
5. System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented

Comment: Humm, the only difference I see is that you define the route handler in Global.asax.cs where I had it in a separate ListHandler.cs file in a Views\Serices folder. Strange ...

Comment: This worked for the _vti_bin/Lists.asmx request. But when I click on the 'About' tab (using the default MVC 2 project) I get the request routed to http://localhost:8888/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?action=About&controller=Home, not to the home controller!